# Page not found error in spring mvc 4 although it exists

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am developing a small application using spring mvc 4 which gets the input from user and inserts it into the database.
Here is the dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="controllers.FormController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

And here is my controller

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {

    @Autowired
    private FormService formService;

    public FormService getFormService() {
        return formService;
    }

    public void setFormService(FormService formService) {
        this.formService = formService;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUser(Model model){
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
    return "index";
}
    @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user, BindingResult result, Model model){
        formService.insert(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return "success";
    }
}
```

When i type the following url in browser "http://localhost:8080/FormSpring/form/userForm.htm", it shows me the page not found error, although the success page is located in the WEB-INF/jsp directory

Here is the web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Also, the structure of the project is shown in the image bellow

[image]

Comment: Try "http://localhost:8080/FormSpring/form/adduser"

Comment: Please share web.xml details as well.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/FormSpring/form/ do u get 404 after hitting this? and index.jsp exist?

Comment: The same error, i have added a snapshot for the project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is mapped to adduser, not adduser.htm! Also in the browser you perform a GET, not a POST request.

Comment: Regarding the GET, i edited the post. I tried removing the .htm from the url but nothing changed.

Comment: <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> you are allowing urls ending in .htm only to be bound to controllers

Comment: what is the problem in this?

Comment: Spring in Action is an excellent book to start with. Read it!

Answer (score 0):

Give the endpoint as of controller, insted of jsp page
Url should be: `http://localhost:8080/FormSpring/form/adduser`

Make sure of proper Request type `POST/GET`